# Correct URL pattern for django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm currently running django version 1.11 and I want to create a blog. I am at the process where I create a function based view to display html content. I keep running into this error.

```
File "/Users/Fanonx/Desktop/xventureblog/src/xventureblog/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
NameError: name 'include' is not defined
```

Here is my code for views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.


def post_home(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello<h1>")
```

here is my code for urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from posts.views import post_home

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^posts/$', post_home),
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't import include from `django.conf.urls`, hence the exception you received (it's quite self-explanatory if you break it down). Your `urls.py` first line should be:

`from django.conf.urls import url, include`

Comment: wow very self-explanatory. Sorry about that, I do appreciate it though!

Comment: Note however that in Django 1.9+ you don't need `include` for the admin urls -- just use `url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),`.

Comment: So say if I want to have the url patterns read from urls.py created from within the app itself (in this case, inside the posts app) instead of the main configuration folder. I tried a similar approach from above, but that does not seem to help

Comment: Note that from Django version 2.0 the URL pattern has changed to use  `django.urls.path()` Check Example here: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/)